# How to read multiple gzipped files from S3 into a single RDD with http request?

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-s3, common-crawl

I have to download many gzipped files stored on S3 like this:

```
crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2018-43/segments/1539583508988.18/robotstxt/CC-MAIN-20181015080248-20181015101748-00000.warc.gz
crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2018-43/segments/1539583508988.18/robotstxt/CC-MAIN-20181015080248-20181015101748-00001.warc.gz
```

to download them you must add the prefix https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/

I have to download and decompress the files,then assemble the content as a single RDD.

Something similar to this:

```
JavaRDD<String> text = 
    sc.textFile("https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2018-43/segments/1539583508988.18/robotstxt/CC-MAIN-20181015080248-20181015101748-00000.warc.gz");
```

I want to do this code with spark:

```
    for (String key : keys) {
        object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));

        gzipStream = new GZIPInputStream(object.getObjectContent());
        decoder = new InputStreamReader(gzipStream);
        buffered = new BufferedReader(decoder);

        sitemaps = new ArrayList<>();

        String line = buffered.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            if (line.matches("Sitemap:.*")) {
                sitemaps.add(line);
            }
            line = buffered.readLine();
        }
```

Comment: There is already a tool which extracts all sitemaps from Common Crawl robots.txt archives: https://github.com/commoncrawl/cc-mrjob/blob/master/sitemaps_from_robotstxt.py
It's Python and based on [mrjob](https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but it would be easy to port it to Spark, cf. [cc-pyspark](https://github.com/commoncrawl/cc-pyspark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read something from S3, you can do this:

```
sc.textFiles("s3n://path/to/dir")
```

If `dir` contains your gzip files, they will be gunzipped and combined into one RDD. If your files are not directly at the root of the directory like this:

```
/root
  /a
    f1.gz
    f2.gz
  /b
    f3.gz
```

or even this:

```
/root
  f3.gz
  /a
    f1.gz
    f2.gz
```

then you should use the wildcard like this `sc.textFiles("s3n://path/to/dir/*")` and spark will recursively find the files in `dir`and its subdirectories.

Beware of [this](https://tech.kinja.com/how-not-to-pull-from-s3-using-apache-spark-1704509219) though. The wildcard will work but you may get lattency issues on S3 in production and may want to use the AmazonS3Client you retrieve the paths.

Comment: What do you mean not yours?

Comment: I found this error The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

Comment: if i use s3n the error is: Relative path in absolute URI: S3ObjectSummary

Comment: Have you tried something like this? `sc.textFile("https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2018-43/segments/1539583508988.18/robotstxt/*")`